# Second ul inside ul needs to be in line with first instead of jumping (margin-left)

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble aligning a second `ul` and bringing it in line with the first `ul`. The second ul always positions itself with a margin. How do I prevent this from happening?

#### Example code

```html
<ul>
    <li><h3 class="category">Lorum Impsum</h3>
  <ul style="display: block;">
   <li><h4 class="subcategory">Lorum ipsum</h4>
   <li><h4 class="question">Ladida!</h4></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Lorum ipsum</p>
 <li>Lorum ipsum</p>
</ul>
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `<ul style="display: block;">` inside your parent ul element to

```
<ul style="display: inline;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/km7Lfjq4/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is to make your `<ul>`'s list horizontally. I think OP wanted them to stay vertical, just without the extra indent

Comment: my mistake! I commented before I saw the fiddle link. Downvote removed.

Comment: Ok no problem, this happens

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
li > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

What this does is removes the left padding from nest unordered lists.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkyC/kko1jjqw/1/

Answer (score 0):

remove the padding?

```css
ul ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><h3 class="category">Lorum Impsum</h3>
  <ul style="display: block;">
   <li><h4 class="subcategory">Lorum ipsum</h4>
   <li><h4 class="question">Ladida!</h4></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Lorum ipsum</p>
 <li>Lorum ipsum</p>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use negative margins to pull your elements in the direction of rather then away from something like so:

```
li ul li {
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

or if you want to scope it to direct children only:

```
li>ul>li {
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```